# Why button color changes to disabled button color when a function is passed as a parameter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, material-design

I have come across the recent changes to flutter buttons and I am using Elevated Button. When I pass a function as a parameter to be set as value for onTap variable of the Elevated Button, its color changes to disabled button color or color that is used when we assign null to onTap as follows.

[image]

Adding the following style property does not change the color:

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.white,
      onPrimary: Colors.amberAccent,)
```

However, if we use ButtonStyle() method it will change the color:

```
style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                    ),
```

[image]

1. Why the color changes to a disabled button color when a function is passed as a parameter?
2. Why ButtonStyle() works and not ElevatedButton.styleFrom()?

Here is the code:

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int i = 0;

  updatePage(int value) {
    setState(() {
      i = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: updatePage(10),
        ),
        MyButton(
          s: '20',
          f: updatePage(20),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String s;
  final Function f;

  MyButton({this.s, this.f});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 40,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(s),
        onPressed: f,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information?

I've tried running the following code and I can't see "disabled color". You can also try to run this code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev)
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void foo() {
    print("hello world");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.white,
                onPrimary: Colors.amberAccent,
              ),
              onPressed: foo,
              child: Text("Elevated Button 1"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: foo,
              child: Text("Elevated Button 2", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amberAccent),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the code in the question. But when I try your code it works. I think we are missing something. Also, for the instance variables  final String s;
  final Function f;, it shows they cannot be null in dart pad, but no such error in android studio. Any idea why?

Comment: I got the solution for this and hope it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468759/why-is-the-print-statement-inside-setstate-is-executed-as-soon-as-the-app-starts