# Why is the print statement inside setState is executed as soon as the app starts?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
      child: Home(),
      ),),
    );
  }
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int i = 0;

  updatePage(int value) {
    setState(() {
      i = value;
      print('$i button clicked');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: updatePage(10),
        ),
        MyButton(
          s: '20',
          f: updatePage(20),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String s;
  final Function f;

  MyButton({this.s, this.f});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 40,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(s),
        onPressed: f,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I thought I was structuring the app correctly in terms of breaking down it into smaller widgets easy to track and update the code. However, the print statements inside the following function are executed as and when app starts and the buttons are also disabled.

```
updatePage(int value) {
setState(() {
  i = value;
  print('$i button clicked');
});
```

}

I am not able to figure out why is this happening and what am I doing incorrectly.

Also, for the instance variables, I am getting null error in dartpad (if I turn off null safety they go away), but android studio does not show any error. Not able to understand why? Is this because null safety is off in android studio? AS and dartpad are on same versions of flutter & dart.

```
  class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String s;
  final Function f;

  MyButton({this.s, this.f});
```

Error that appears in dartpad but not in AS:
[image]

I am pretty much beginner to flutter and a detailed help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you to the community for such a quick response. It is very encouraging when beginners like me face issues and feel discouraging that we are not able to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the other answers already tell you how to solve your problem. Just as a didactic explanation of why this is happening:

When you do this:

```
MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: updatePage(10),
        )
```

you are calling the function `updatePage(10)` and using the result of this function call as the input to the parameter `f`.

To pass a Function, you can't use the `()` parenthesis. If you use the parenthesis you are calling the function itself and then it will represent its return value. *This is why the print statement is being called on your example.*

So, to call a function, you should use the function name without parameters:

```
MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: updatePage,
        )
```

This will pass the `updatePage` itself to the `MyButton` widget, and not its return value. However, this way you can't pass the `10` parameter you wanted. So, the way to solve this is to create a new [anonymous function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions) that only calls `updatePage` with the `10` parameter:

```
MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: ()=>updatePage(10),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the reasoning what I was exactly looking for. And regarding the instance variables' null warning, is that because of null safety? I am beginner to not just flutter, but programming in general. Can you suggest what may be best way to get the basics/core concepts like this clear as clarity on these help a lot.

Comment: @ar3 Oh. It would be nice to include the error message in the question itself, but I believe the mistake is because you didn't set the parameters as required on the constructor: ```MyButton({required this.s, required this.f});```. Without the required it is an optional parameter and therefore it may be null if not passed. Your parameters cannot be null if not explicitly stated. You should read the [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) articles on the official site.

Comment: I have added the image showing the error. Yes when I add required keyword, they go away. I believe this is because of null safety only then. I will go through the official docs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the instance variables being null and seeing the print statement to be executed is that you do not pass the function to the newly created instance but call the function and pass the return value (that is null in this case because of a void function).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Home(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int i = 0;

  updatePage(int value) {
    setState(() {
      i = value;
      print('$i button clicked');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyButton(
          s: '10',
          f: updatePage,
        ),
        MyButton(
          s: '20',
          f: updatePage,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String s;
  final Function f;

  MyButton({this.s, this.f});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 40,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(s),
        onPressed: () => f(int.parse(s)),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, how can we rectify this instead of passing null function please? And for the instance variables where we get null error, I think it is due to null safety enabled as per the diagnostic docs page. But not sure completely.

Comment: I added the fixed example above. This should work as expected.

Comment: Yes this works as expected. Only thing is if I move the MyButton class to a new dart file, it will not able to access the 'updatePage' passed through f. Using <MyButton(s: '10',f: () => updatePage(10)),> works fine, but not sure what is the reason. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You dont need to call the method from MyButton explictly. Just call the reference you passed. updatePage() should live in the _HomeState since it sets its state. Moving just the class in a separate file works for me.

Comment: Yes it works fine. I guess I need to focus more on the basics. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this,

```
MyButton(s: '10',f: () => updatePage(10)),
```

Comment: Ok this works as expected. Can you please help me understand why this is working and what was the mistake in my code.

Comment: If you dig deep into the tree the button use gesture detector onTap method and it looks like  this

` if (tap.onTap != null)
        tap.onTap();`
So you need to pass a callback function which contains your logic so that callback function will executes your logic

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

replace  `onPressed: f,` with  `onPressed:()=> f(),`

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String s;
  final Function f;

  MyButton({this.s, this.f});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 40,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(s),
        onPressed:()=> f(),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and while using it

```
  MyButton(
    s: "10",
    f: () => updatePage(3),
        ),
```

Comment: are you using null-safety?

Comment: I am not sure if null safety is enabled. I will see how to check it. Using just 2nd part of your suggestion resolves the issue. <MyButton(
    s: "10",
    f: () => updatePage(3),
        ),>. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: can you check this answer, let me know if anything goes wrong